# Using Ag ("The Silver Searcher") to find hex codes

Tags: bash, shell, ag

I used to use find command for linux to find hex code in php code as the following:

```
find "/www_root/myfile" -type f -name "*.php" | xargs grep -il x29
```

The above command works like a charm, but I may need a faster searcher as my files are keep growing.

I would like to test using [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) `ag` Command, and I have been searching around of how to find hex code using "ag" command, but cannot find any in their documentation. So, here I am in this forum, seeking for answer in the hope someone has experienced on searching hex code using the silver searcher `ag`.

Comment: I'm confused. You appear to be searching for a literal string of `x29` not a "hex code". Does that not just work with `ag`? Or is that command not what you were actually doing?

Comment: Indeed, the search string is a _literal_ string that just _happens to be_ the textual representation of a hex. code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, I did not found this a bit earlier, but now has been found. What I did not understand was actually the "ag" command and functions that could be used but now it's ok.

I will share the answer here just in case someone might need it. In order to replace the find command as I questioned previously, we can use this:

```
ag --php -l 'x29' "/www_root/myfile"
```

Output of the previous command would be something like:

```
/www_root/myfile/menus.php
```

If it found more files, then it will list files separated by new line "\n":

```
/www_root/myfile/menus.php
/www_root/myfile/contents.php
```

If you would like to know which line numbers, you can then drop the "-l" attribute and then replace it with "--numbers":

```
ag --php --numbers 'x29' "/www_root/myfile"
```

Output:

```
30:matches string found here
89:matches string found here
```

Ok, now we can combine it with "cut" command to get only the line numbers:

```
ag --php --numbers 'x29' "/www_root/myfile" | cut -f1 -d:
```

Output:

```
30
89
```

Most of the commands are similar to "ack", so for you who wants to use "ag" can find "ack" documentation as they have documented everything.

Last but not least, if you would like to know the statistic, you can add --stats to the above command as the following:

```
ag --php -l --stats 'x29' "/www_root/myfile"
```

That simple command will output as the result shown:

```
31 matches
1624 files searched
18686162 bytes searched
0.094022 seconds
```

So, yes, choosing The Silver Searcher was the right choice. That's all and have a great day.

Comment: Nice. While `ag`'s own documentation is scant, it _does_ come with a `man` page. `--php` is an example of a _file type_ supported by `ag`, which matches _multiple_ filename extensions (suffixes). Run `ag --list-file-types` to see all available types. `ag`, similar to its progenitor `ack`, searches _recursively_ by default.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at [findrepo](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/findrepo) which you could use like:

```
cd /www_root/myfile && findrepo -n 'x29' '*.php'
```

That should be faster than `ag` (and I'm surprised you said that your initial `find | xargs grep` command was slower than `ag`)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but can you provide more info on how to use? Regarding find | xargs grep I have tested by executing time command which shows: 

real 0m0.915s

The following was executed by using ag:

real 0m0.087s